# Where to propose a new app for elementary OS, discuss design

Tags: gtk

Where is the best place for ask a new app:
- propose requirement
- publish proposed mockups

I've seen bountysource is linked with launchpad, but launchpad doesn't seems the proper tool for requirement and discuss mockups...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

There were some of such proposals over there at [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/communities/104613975513761463450). Try it there. Perhaps you will find some developers. However, there is no official platform. Bountysource has an platform for elementary's own applications.